# ORA-00947 : Not Enough Values while putting values into a type inside a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types, ora-00947

I have created some Oracle types:

```
create or replace TYPE "RESULTS_ADMIN" AS OBJECT 
(
  ROWNUMBER NUMBER,
  ASSET_ID VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR),
  BOOK_ID VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
  asset_name VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) ,
  book_author VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) , 
  asset_location VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
  asset_cat VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
  asset_type VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
  publisher_name VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  books_available NUMBER
);

create or replace TYPE "RESULT_ADMIN_TEMP" is table of LMS.results_admin;
```

Here is a procedure which uses them:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "RETRIEVE_ASSET_ADMIN" (
     aid IN asset_details.asset_id%TYPE,
      aname IN asset_details.asset_name%TYPE,
      acat IN asset_details.asset_cat%type,
      atypeid IN asset_details.asset_type_id%type,
      bauthor IN asset_details.book_author%type,
      aloc IN asset_details.asset_location%type,
      pub IN asset_publisher.publisher_name%type,
      pagenumber IN number,
      asset_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR    )
is 
    v_fpgnbr number;
    v_pgsize number;
    v_frec number;
    v_lrec number;
    v_totrows number;
    result_admin_temp_table result_admin_temp;
begin
  v_fpgnbr := pagenumber;
  v_pgsize :=10;
  v_frec := (v_fpgnbr - 1 ) * v_pgsize;
  v_lrec := ( v_fpgnbr * v_pgsize + 1 ); 
  select  row_number() over (order by a.asset_id) as rownum,
          a.asset_id, 
          a.book_id, 
          asset_name ,
          book_author , 
          asset_location, 
          asset_cat , 
          l.asset_type, 
          p.publisher_name,
          c.books_available
      bulk collect into result_admin_temp_table
  from asset_details a join asset_count c 
      on a.book_id=c.book_id 
      join asset_lookup_details l 
      on a.asset_type_id=l.asset_type_id 
      join asset_publisher p
      on a.book_id = p.book_id
  where (aid is NULL or a.asset_id = aid ) and 
      (aname is NULL or asset_name like '%'||aname||'%') and 
      (bauthor is NULL or book_author like '%'||bauthor||'%') and 
      (aloc like '%SELECT%' or asset_location like '%'|| aloc ||'%') and 
      (acat like '%SELECT%' or asset_cat like '%'||acat||'%') and 
      (atypeid = 0 or a.asset_type_id = atypeid) and
      (pub is NULL or p.publisher_name like '%'||pub||'%');
  open asset_cur for
  select 
      asset_id, 
      book_id, 
      asset_name ,
      book_author , 
      asset_location, 
      asset_cat , 
      asset_type, 
      publisher_name,
      books_available 
  from table(result_admin_temp_table)
  where 
  rownum > v_frec and rownum < v_lrec
  order by rownum asc;
end RETRIEVE_ASSET_ADMIN;
```

While I am compiling the code, I am getting `ORA-00947: Not enough values error at the "bulkcollect into result_admin_temp_table" point`. I have tried a lot to search over the internet to find out a resolution to this.
Can you  please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why you get that message: you are selecting into a nested table.  Oracle won't cast a result set to a type for you: you need to do it yourself.

```
select RESULTS_ADMIN(
          row_number() over (order by a.asset_id),
          a.asset_id, 
          a.book_id, 
          asset_name ,
          book_author , 
          asset_location, 
          asset_cat , 
          l.asset_type, 
          p.publisher_name,
          c.books_available )
  bulk collect into result_admin_temp_table
  from asset_details a join asset_count c 
      on a.book_id=c.book_id 
      join asset_lookup_details l 
      on a.asset_type_id=l.asset_type_id 
      join asset_publisher p
      on a.book_id = p.book_id)
```

Some additional observations:

1. Don't use `rownum` as an alias.  ROWNUM is [an Oracle keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255), and so your query won't work the way you think it will.
2. You are populating a nested table with the entire result set. Collections sit in session memory.   If the query returns many results - and given how vague the parameters are I would guess sometimes it will - the collection might grow too large and blow the PGA limit.
3. Running paginating queries in the database is such a bad idea.  Nobody wants to put business logic in the database yet everybody wants to put presentation logic there.  *shakes head*

Finally, you could avoid the overhead of the collection with a simple in-line query:

```
open asset_cur for
  select 
      asset_id, 
      book_id, 
      asset_name ,
      book_author , 
      asset_location, 
      asset_cat , 
      asset_type, 
      publisher_name,
      books_available 
  from (  select  row_number() over (order by a.asset_id) as rn,
              a.asset_id, 
              a.book_id, 
              asset_name ,
              book_author , 
              asset_location, 
              asset_cat , 
              l.asset_type, 
              p.publisher_name,
              c.books_available
          bulk collect into result_admin_temp_table
      from asset_details a join asset_count c 
          on a.book_id=c.book_id 
          join asset_lookup_details l 
          on a.asset_type_id=l.asset_type_id 
          join asset_publisher p
          on a.book_id = p.book_id
      where (aid is NULL or a.asset_id = aid ) and 
          (aname is NULL or asset_name like '%'||aname||'%') and 
          (bauthor is NULL or book_author like '%'||bauthor||'%') and 
          (aloc like '%SELECT%' or asset_location like '%'|| aloc ||'%') and 
          (acat like '%SELECT%' or asset_cat like '%'||acat||'%') and 
          (atypeid = 0 or a.asset_type_id = atypeid) and
          (pub is NULL or p.publisher_name like '%'||pub||'%')
          ) t
  where t.rn > v_frec and t.rn < v_lrec
  order by t.rn asc;
```